# Magento 2 Add custom products to product collection on catalog page - pagination not working

Tags: magento2.4, category-products, category-listing, category-view

I need to add some custom products to category pages. Just to test this I've created twenty dummy products based on the last product in the category list. In ListProduct.php - initializeProductCollection() I added the following code:

```
        $collection = $layer->getProductCollection();

        $dummyIdArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

        foreach ($collection as $k => $product) { }

        foreach ($dummyIdArray as $dummyId) {

            $newProduct = $this->productFactory->create();

            $newProduct->setData($product->getData());
            $newProduct->setName('Dummy Name: '.$dummyId);
            $newProduct->setId($dummyId);
            $newProduct->setRequestPath('dummy'.$dummyId.'.html');
            $collection->addItem($newProduct);
        }
```

This correctly adds 20 extra products to the collection and they display correctly on the category page.

However the pagination does not work in two ways:

- The pagination lists the correct number of pages for the original collection. So for a collection of 13 real items it shows 2 pages when the limit is 10 products per page.
- Both pages list all 13 real items and the 20 extra products
- The toolbar reads 'Items 1-33 of 13'

I can resolve the third issue by changing getTotalNum() in Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php to

```
count($this->getCollection());
```

Then it reads 'Items 1-33 of 33' but the limit is set to '10' so it should be 'Items 1-10 of 33'

In ListProduct.php there is a comment:

- - Product collection may be requested internally from the current Catalog Layer.

But I can't see where it does this as I suspect it has something to do with the errors.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated!